# Changing to another users account to access files in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Basically I want to change directory but to another users account how do I do this is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `su`, then the command to run as the user:

```
$ su otheruser
$ cd /home/otheruser
```

Comment: "Sudo: cd: command not found".    Is the response i get when I do this

Comment: Ah, I forgot that `sudo` doesn't work with builtins (`cd` being one of them). My apologies. I have updated my answer.

Comment: When I put that command in and the password for that. Nothing  happens it just returns to the terminal

Comment: student@MINT9 ~ $ su mintuser -c cd /home/mintuserPassword:
student@MINT9 ~ $  


this happens

Comment: The command probably worked and you are indeed in mintuser's home directory. Type `pwd` to verify.

Comment: No worries. Try splitting the command into two:

`$ su mintuser`
and then
`$ cd /home/mintuser`

Answer (score 0):

You can switch user and get a shell with the command su < username >, you must know the password for that user though. If you want to execute a single command instead of having a full shell add that command with the -c switch. Man pages [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su)